# Image compression in gulp

Tags: image, gulp, compression

We have been using gulp-imagemin in gulp for a while with good results, however recently Google page speed reporting has been complaining that our images are not optimised.
We manually ran them through this tool http://compresspng.com/ and it gave us over 50% lossless compression on images previously run through gulp-imagemin.

Is there a gulp tool that has better compression out there?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Tinypng? 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tinypng-compress

Also, this thread can help you in your research as it has a lot of valuable information on the subject of image compression:
[Improve PNG optimization Gulp task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896407/improve-png-optimization-gulp-task#29141835)

Hope this helps. 
N.

Answer (score -1):

Try [ImageKit.io](https://imagekit.io), it automatically handles image optimization. At the same time, you can resize, rotate and crop images using URL parameters. You can integrate ImageKit very easily within few minutes. Give it a try.